# Qt postgresql delete record

Tags: c++, database, qt

I'm working on Qt 4.8-Postgresql application,I'm Using the following code to delete a database record the code works perfect, but if there is a data related to that table in another table an

> error 23503 foreign_key_violation

raised till now everything is OK. Now if I delete the data related in the other table and execute the same code again to delete the same record,

> error 42601 raised indicating syntax error at or near "(" LINE 1:
>   EXECUTE (77831, '30').

What could be the reason?

```
 QSqlQuery query ;
    query.prepare("DELETE FROM purchasing.invoice WHERE OID=:Oid AND    invoice_id=:invoice_id ") ;

   query.bindValue(":Oid" , Oid);
   query.bindValue(":invoice_id" , ui->invoice_id->text() );

   query.exec();
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Is it possible that this is a bug in qt, and the prepared statement name is passing out of scope?